# How long can i write, using Blob write From iphone To CC2540?(BLE)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How long can i write, using Blob write From iphone To CC2540?(BLE)

i use iphone write a Characteristic about 252 byte(write Long Characteristic Value), but iphone return unknow Error, MayBe the 2540 is timeout?

short msg length(but can write only 90 byte) have no problem. does the 2540 have some limit to Blob write?